# dotnet build - get error "could not return the default page '/index.html'"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, binary

try to generate my project into exe file, but get error:

**before: "dotnet build -r win10-x86" is ok**

**after run generated exe, all is ok also:**

```
indows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:....\currencyColution\correncyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\win10-x86
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

**after load page is somwthing worng, more precisely index.html is not found:**

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLG91TC2H0UO", Request id "0HLG91TC2H0UO:00000001": An 

unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace AspNetCore2Ang6Template
{
  public class Startup
  {
  
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddMvc();
      services.AddSpaStaticFiles(c =>
      {
        c.RootPath = "wwwroot";
      });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action=index}/{id}");
      });

      app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
      });

    }
  }
}
```

I dont't use angular and some other ones, just try to open wwwroot/index.html

> files:
>
> currencyProject
>
> ```
> wwwroot
>
> Program.cs
>
> Startup.cs
> ```

Tested in VS , all works, but not via exe builder

**launched like dev : dotnet run, then it works on localhost:58893/, but what is wrong with prod dotnet build on localhost:5000**

**launchSettings:**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58842/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AspNetCore2Ang6Template": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58893/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do the same, it is working for me. How do you launch the exe ? Any param added or smth ? Which version of .Net are you using ?

Comment: @Zysce, Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 2.1.1, exe launched as Admin and User, without any params

Comment: @Zysce, maybe Port, 5000, 5001 set exe builder, but via IDE port is 58843 and it works

Comment: @Zysce, I use Windows 10 on VMware Fusion, dotnet 2.1.4

Comment: @Zysce, launched like dev : dotnet run, then it works on localhost:58893/, but what is wrong with prod dotnet build on localhost:5000

Comment: When I launched the exe, it works for localhost:5000. Can you add your launchSettings ?

Comment: @Zysce, ofcourse, but where should I take them?

Comment: If you use VS, in the properties folder, there should have a launchSettings.json file

Comment: @Zysce, added above

Comment: @Zysce, I think, Port 5000 taken when I run exe, in VS I can't run port 5000 too, error: System.IO.IOException: "Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem come from the fact when you build the project with the command dotnet build, the wwwroot folder is not copied.

I reproduced your problem, to fix it, I copied the folder in the output and it worked.

You should use the publish command to test production.

In either cases, both commands don't copy the wwwroot folder.

Comment: I think you can check this
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/7618#issuecomment-275932671

Answer (score 17):

check angular.json file use   `"outputPath": "dist",`

And Startup file

```
 services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
      {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
      });
```

Comment: These options are set in my environment, however I still got the same error.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti I got similar issue though have the above config. Then I run the `ng build` command and it got fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Resolved this issue by comparing existing Angular Asp net core template, I did following code changes.

**In csproj file:**

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
 <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
 <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
 <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
 <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

 <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
 <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
 <UserSecretsId>baa2f579-d2a7-4eb4-89fb-1c171b2e2482</UserSecretsId>
 <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>

<ItemGroup>
 <TypeScriptCompile Include="App\src\app\models\user.ts" />
 <TypeScriptCompile Include="App\src\app\utils\AppContants.ts" />
 <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
 <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
 <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
 <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
 <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
 <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
   <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
 </Exec>
 <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
 <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
 <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="ng build --prod" />
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

 <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
 <ItemGroup>
   <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
   <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
   <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
     <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
     <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
   </ResolvedFileToPublish>
 </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

**In Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

 app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

**In Angular angular.json**

```
 "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist",
```

Comment: I think you mean `angular.json` not `package.json`. I'm surprised though since you're using SSR. Wouldn't your outputPath need to be "dist/browser"? Which section of your `package.json` did you alter?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because I added a new environment named "LocalDevelopment," but didn't update the target for the the IsEnvironment call in Startup.cs

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsEnvironment("LocalDevelopment"))
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that another reason this error can happen is if your controller route attributes don't exactly match the request URL.

For example, your client request is:

```
https://myapp/myapi/mycontroller/myapiaction
```

But the controller in your dotnet app has a mismatched attribute for the intended endpoint

```
// Note api in the route doesn't match myapi in the request
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] 
public class MyController
   :
   :
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after a git branch switch.
I had to install the node modules again:

```
npm install
```

From this [answer](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1514#issuecomment-363835983) on GitHub. Note that this solution only can help if you're using Node.js as part of your frontend stack.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was type error in enviroment.prod.ts `pathApi: "/api/"`, I just removed last "/"

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after a visual studio update where some of the features were not installed properly.
My solution was to clean the visual studio cache:

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager).
2. Delete the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.x\ComponentModelCache` directory.
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Then try to run the application again.
Probably, it would suggest you to install the feature : [Development time IIS support for ASP.NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/)